# Flexslider is not working in Angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript

Iam working in Angular4.Iam trying to display images in a carousel using flexslider and images data is getting from API.I have included flexslider.css and flexslider.js files in my index.html file,and I included the script code in my current html file.But Iam not getting any data and flexslider is not working.Below is my code:

```js
 <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides" *ngFor="let image of productInfo.images">
                        <li>
                            <img src="{{image.src}}" />
                        </li>
                        <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="carousel" class="flexslider" *ngFor="let image of productInfo.images">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li>
                            <img src="{{image.src}}" />
                        </li>
                        <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <script>
                    $('#carousel').flexslider({
                        animation: "slide",
                        controlNav: false,
                        animationLoop: false,
                        slideshow: false,
                        itemWidth: 210,
                        itemMargin: 5,
                        asNavFor: '#slider'
                    });

                    $('#slider').flexslider({
                        animation: "slide",
                        controlNav: false,
                        animationLoop: false,
                        slideshow: false,
                        sync: "#carousel"
                    });

                </script>
            </div>
```

```html
<!--
Author: W3layouts
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SimplySaltApp</title>
    <base href="/">
    <!-- for-mobile-apps -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Best Store Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Android Compatible web template, 
Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript">
        addEventListener("load", function() {
            setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
        }, false);

        function hideURLbar() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        }

    </script>
    <!-- //for-mobile-apps -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <!-- Demo CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!-- Modernizr -->
    <script src="assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- js -->
    <!--    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- //js -->
    <!-- cart -->
    <script src="assets/js/simpleCart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cart -->
    <!-- for bootstrap working -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- //for bootstrap working -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- timer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.countdown.css" />
    <!-- //timer -->
    <!-- animation-effect -->
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        new WOW().init();

    </script>
    <!-- //animation-effect -->
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your controller class

```
ngDoCheck(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify a little bit more about this answer? (why is this the answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you have an ordering issue.

If you set up FlexSlider *before* Angular has done it's work, you're ordering causes the following behaviour:

1. FlexSlider initializes, on the single template element
2. Angular runs and removes the template from the DOM, replacing it with the actual content
3. Misery ensues

You need to initialize FlexSlider *after* Angular has done its stuff...

1. Angular runs and removes the template from the DOM, replacing it with the actual content
2. FlexSlider initializes on the content Angular created
3. Happiness ensues